# uno + ethernet sheild(wiznet) + dh22 temp humidity sensor + viewing data online

Tags: arduino-uno

i am new to arduino and have no experience with programming

i have an uno r3 board, a wiznet ethernet sheild, and dh22 temp and humidity sensor.

```
  I would like to have it update plot.ly to view the data.
```

error returned on monitor is ...

```
POST /clientresp HTTP/1.1
Host: plot.ly:80
User-Agent: Arduino/0.6.0
Content-Length: 340

version=2.3&origin=plot&platform=arduino&un=jozef.jones&key=tgcio4brx1&args=[{"y": [], "x": [], "type": "scatter", "stream": {"token": "ke1f6fwqas", "maxpoints": 100}}, {"y": [], "x": [], "type": "scatter", "stream": {"token": "k5lmga9qrl", "maxpoints": 100}}]&kwargs={"fileopt": "overwrite", "filename": "filename", "world_readable": true}
... Sent message, waiting for plotly's response...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 17 Jan 2016 16:22:32 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=WknqVtPqjTYvlTyoKSC5QehqDgmt7Qp7; expires=Tue, 17-Jan-2017 16:22:32 GMT; Max-Age=31622400; Path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: anoncsrf=2UDFDiQhQq1zf5MIMaoRJ0ayaqs7g58R; expires=Mon, 18-Jan-2016 16:22:32 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=86400; Path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Vary: Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 138
Connection: keep-alive

{"url": "", "message": "", "warning": "", "filename": "", "error": "Missing required POST parameters: platform un key origin args kwargs"}
```

code is

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include "plotly_streaming_ethernet.h"
#include "DHT.h"


#define nTraces 2

char *tokens[nTraces] = {"ke1f6fwqas", "k5lmga9qrl"};
// arguments: username, api key, streaming token, filename
plotly graph("jozef.jones", "tgcio4brx1", tokens, "filename", nTraces);

// DHT Sensor Setup
#define DHTPIN 2 // We have connected the DHT to Digital Pin 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT22 // This is the type of DHT Sensor (Change it to DHT11 if you're using that model)
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE); // Initialize DHT object

byte mac[] = { 0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0x00, 0x00, 0xCC };
byte my_ip[] = { 192, 168, 1, 117 }; // google will tell you: "public ip address"

void startEthernet(){
    Serial.println("... Initializing ethernet");
    if(Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0){
        Serial.println("... Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
        // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
        // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
        Ethernet.begin(mac, my_ip);
    }
    Serial.println("... Done initializing ethernet");
    delay(1000);
}


void setup() {
  graph.maxpoints = 100;
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }

  startEthernet();

  bool success;
  success = graph.init();
  if(!success){while(true){}}
  graph.openStream();
  dht.begin();
}

float h, t;

void loop() {
      h = dht.readHumidity();
      t = dht.readTemperature();
      graph.plot(millis(), t, tokens[0]);
      graph.plot(millis(), h, tokens[1]);
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a more common problem (http://community.plot.ly/t/arduino-streaming-data-issue-missing-required-post-parameters/304). You should encode the values of `args` and `kwargs`. But that didn't fix the error message when I tried it myself.